# Issue in routing in react js website. Cannot load main page

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am building a website in Reactjs as client-side and Nodejs as the backend.

I wish to add client-side routing to the application.
All imports are included in each individual file.
The code is as below:

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <App />
   
 , document.getElementById('app'))
```

**public/index.html**

```
<div id="app"></app>
```

**App.js**

```
 return (
<BrowserRouter>
<div>   
<div className="collapse
navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
                
                    <ul className="navbar-nav m-auto">
                          <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/" className="nav-link">Home </Link></li>
                          <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/about" className="nav-link">About Us </Link></li>
                          <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/trainer" className="nav-link">Trainer </Link></li>
                      <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/classes" className="nav-link">Classes </Link></li>
                          <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/disclaimer" className="nav-link">Disclaimer </Link></li>
                          
                    </ul> 
                    <Switch>
                         <Route exact path="/" component={App} /> 
                        <Route path="/trainer" component={Trainer} />
                        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                        <Route path="/classes" component={Classes} />
                        <Route path="/disclaimer" component={Disclaimer} />
                        </Switch>
                     </div></div></BrowserRouter> )
```

However, on localhost:3000 I just see a rotating screen and it does not load the main page.
How should I fix this?

Comment: It seems to me that component App is being called eternally, since it's used inside the switch and as the name of the root component.

Comment: Yes @RodrigoAmaral is correct. Remove `App` as your root component as let us know if that helps